# Transition animation starting position wrong place

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-transitions

I'm having problems with android transition. I have a recyclerview list with multiple elements. The animation should start from any row's image when clicked, but it doesn't, it starts from the middle of the row.

I have a fragment with a RecyclerView, here is where the transition begins

**fragment_states:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="namespace.fragments.StatesFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewStates"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

The previous recyclerView has a list adapter where a row is defined as shown below. Here I defined android:transitionName="stateImage", is the image from where the transition should start.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgState"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:transitionName="stateImage"
        android:padding="6dp" />
<TextView
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgState"
    android:id="@+id/txtNombreEstado"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's how I call the transition:

**StatesFragment.java**

```
public class StatesFragment extends Fragment {
...
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new Helper.RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new Helper.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {

                try {    
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CitiesActivity.class);

                    //Check if we're running on Android 5.0 or higher
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        // Call some material design APIs here
                        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                                makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), view, "stateImage");
                        startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
                    } else {
                        // Implement this feature without material design
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));
}
```

Any idead on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was in this line:

```
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                                makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), view, "stateImage");
```

I was passing the view, in this case the row. This is how I fixed it

```
 final ImageView image = (ImageView)
                            view.findViewById(R.id.stateImage);

ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                                makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), image, "stateImage");
```